# Show if one series converges absolutely then so too does the other.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Task at hand:
Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be nonzero complex numbers for $n=1,2,3...$ . Suppose $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left|\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right|=l$ exists, and $l\neq0,\infty.$ show that if one of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges absolutely, then so too does the other. In particular, the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nz^n$ have the same radii of convergence.

I aaas trying to prove the absolute convergence part using the ratio test but that was not working for me. Also I am unsure of how the radii of convergence is going to play a part in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convergence implies an inequality of the form
\begin{equation}
\frac{l}{2} \leq \frac{|a_n|}{|b_n|} \leq \frac{3l}{2}
\end{equation}
valid for all sufficiently large $n$. Simply pick $\epsilon = \frac{l}{2} > 0$. This will allow you to use one series to dominate the other as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely.
To test convergence it doesn't hurt to drop finitely many summands. So we drop all those with $\left|\frac {a_n}{b_n}\right|\ge l+1$ and thus may assume $|a_n|<l+1$. Then $$\sum_{n=M}^N|a_n|< (l+1) \sum_{n=M}^N|b_n| $$
for all $M,N\in\Bbb N$, $M<N$. 
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
Per absolute convergence of $b_n$, there exists $N_0$ such that $N>M>N_0$ implies $ \sum_{n=M}^N|b_n| <\frac\epsilon{l+1}$ and hence for those $N,M$ also $\sum_{n=M}^N|a_n|<\epsilon$. We conclude that $a_n$ converges absolutely.

As the given condition is symmetric in $a_n,b_n$ (if we replace $l$ with $\frac 1l$), the reverse direction also holds, i.e., absolute convergence of $a_n$ implies absolute convergence of $b_n$.

Regarding the power series observe that $\left|\frac{a_nz^n}{b_nz^n}\right|=\left|\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right|$.